# Get dynamically generated attribute value on click

Tags: c#

I have a hidden field in a form where I have a default value set in the markup:

```
<input id="hiddenField" type="hidden" runat="server" value="0" />
```

I dynamically set the value of the field via client side JS function...that works and my field ends up looking like:

```
<input id="hiddenField" type="hidden" runat="server" value="7" />
```

What Im trying to do is to grab that value when this button is clicked:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button" runat="server" OnClick="Button_Click" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn" />
```

And from there use it in my code behind to perform something.

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string itemToCheck = hiddenField.Value;
        //do something with itemToCheck
    }
```

Problem is that the value returned is 0, which is the default value.  As I mentioned, the value is changed via client side JS, and I confirm that part works.  The purpose of this is to create a variable that can be used on submit to check a value, even something simple like:

```
if (itemToCheck >= 2){
    //do something
}
```

...so Im not tied to the hidden field, or the value attribute for that matter...just using this as a hacky way to pass a value from one point to another.

Also, even though I am able to use JS to set the attribute the solution needs to be in C# to use the result as needed....unless theres a way to do it in JS and pass the result to C#.

Comment: How is the default value of `0` being set? Just in the markup or in the `Page_Load`? If it is being set int `Page_Load` without being guarded by `!IsPostBack`, then the page load will overwrite the value on post backs back to the default.

Comment: Its set in the markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a normal ASP.Net textbox to the page and then hide it when the page is loaded at the client.  Then, you can manipulate the value using JavaScript and jQuery.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input#<% =txtTest.ClientID %>').val(9);
        $('input#<% =txtTest.ClientID %>').hide();
    }) 
</script>
```

Then, you can read the textbox value on the server side:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var x = txtTest.Text;
    }
```